# MACRO works in stepping through but breaks when run via button

Tags: vba, excel

I had created a Macro that reads data from a sheet and create journal entries. I had to update the macro due to some changes to the spreadsheet however now my macro doesnt work.

My macro works if I step through the entire thing or if I hit the play button in the VSB screen. However If I hit the macro button I embedded in spreadsheet, it breaks. I believe its breaking because its skipping this section:

```
  If Cells(iRow2, 1) = "CCC $" Then
    wsUp.Cells(iRow2, 1).Value = "CC"
    ElseIf Cells(iRow2, 1) = "DDD $" Then
```

I am not sure why it is skipping this only when I bit the embedded button and not when I run it from the VSB screen.

```
Sub CreateAllocations_JEs()

Dim iRow As Integer, iCol As Integer, iRow2 As Integer
Dim sEntity As String, sEnt2 As String, sVal1 As String, sEnt3 As String, sDesc2 As String
Dim wsEntry As Worksheet
Dim wsUp As Worksheet
Dim wsInst As Worksheet
Set wsInst = Worksheets("Instructions")
Set wsEntry = Worksheets("Entries")
Set wsUp = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim sRange As Range
Dim sQLNE As Long

''' Creates expense for holdings
For iRow = 6 To 35
    lastrow = wsUp.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    sEntity = wsEntry.Range("D5").Value
    sAcct = wsEntry.Range("N" & iRow).Value
    sAcct2 = wsEntry.Range("M" & iRow).Value
    sDesc = wsEntry.Range("O" & iRow).Value
    vsum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(wsEntry.Range("E" & iRow & ":J" & iRow))
    If vsum > 0 Then
    wsUp.Range("A" & lastrow + 1).Value = sEntity
    wsUp.Range("J" & lastrow + 1).Value = vsum
    wsUp.Range("G" & lastrow + 1).Value = sAcct
''''' Adds description column using the companies that have payables
    sDesc2 = ""
    End If
    For iCol = 5 To 12
        If wsEntry.Cells(iRow, iCol) > 0 Then
        sEnt3 = wsEntry.Cells(5, iCol).Value
            If sDesc2 <> "" Then
            sDesc2 = sDesc2 & ", "
            End If
        sDesc2 = sDesc2 & sEnt3
        End If

    Next iCol
    wsUp.Range("M" & lastrow + 1).Value = sDesc & sDesc2

    '''''' Creates receivable for holdings and related fields
    For iCol = 5 To 10
        If wsEntry.Cells(iRow, iCol) > "0" Then
        sVal1 = wsEntry.Cells(iRow, iCol).Value
        sDesc = wsEntry.Range("O" & iRow).Value
        sEnt3 = wsEntry.Cells(5, iCol).Value
        lastrow = wsUp.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        wsUp.Range("A" & lastrow + 1).Value = sEntity
        wsUp.Range("I" & lastrow + 1).Value = sVal1
        vRec = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("IC accounts").Range("C:C"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheets("Entries").Cells(5, iCol), Sheets("IC accounts").Range("B:B"), 0), 1)
        wsUp.Range("G" & lastrow + 1).Value = vRec
        wsUp.Range("M" & lastrow + 1).Value = sDesc & sEnt3
        End If
    Next iCol

    ''''Creates the payables and expense in other companies
    For iCol = 5 To 12

        If wsEntry.Cells(iRow, iCol) > "0" Then
        sEnt2 = wsEntry.Cells(5, iCol).Value
        sval2 = wsEntry.Cells(iRow, iCol).Value
        lastrow = wsUp.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        wsUp.Range("A" & lastrow + 1, "A" & lastrow + 2).Value = sEnt2
            If wsUp.Range("A" & lastrow + 1).Value = "AAA $" Then
                wsUp.Range("J" & lastrow + 1).Value = sval2
                wsUp.Range("I" & lastrow + 2).Value = sval2
                wsUp.Range("G" & lastrow + 1).Value = sAcct2
                wsUp.Range("G" & lastrow + 2).Value = "00-1320001"
            ElseIf wsUp.Range("A" & lastrow + 1).Value = "BBB $" Then
                wsUp.Range("J" & lastrow + 1).Value = sval2
                wsUp.Range("I" & lastrow + 2).Value = sval2
                wsUp.Range("G" & lastrow + 1).Value = sAcct2
                wsUp.Range("G" & lastrow + 2).Value = "00-1320002"
            Else
                wsUp.Range("I" & lastrow + 1).Value = sval2
                wsUp.Range("J" & lastrow + 2).Value = sval2
                wsUp.Range("G" & lastrow + 1).Value = sAcct2
                wsUp.Range("G" & lastrow + 2).Value = "00-4100040"
            End If
        wsUp.Range("M" & lastrow + 1, "M" & lastrow + 2).Value = sDesc & sEntity
        End If


    Next iCol

Next iRow

    lastrow = wsUp.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For iRow2 = 2 To lastrow

    If Cells(iRow2, 1) = "CCC $" Then
    wsUp.Cells(iRow2, 1).Value = "CC"
    ElseIf Cells(iRow2, 1) = "DDD $" Then
    wsUp.Cells(iRow2, 1).Value = "DD"
    ElseIf Cells(iRow2, 1) = "EEE $" Then
    wsUp.Cells(iRow2, 1).Value = "EE"
    ElseIf Cells(iRow2, 1) = "FFF $" Then
    wsUp.Cells(iRow2, 1).Value = "FF"
    ElseIf Cells(iRow2, 1) = "GGG $" Then
    wsUp.Cells(iRow2, 1).Value = "GG"
    ElseIf Cells(iRow2, 1) = "HHH $" Then
    wsUp.Cells(iRow2, 1).Value = "LLL"
    ElseIf Cells(iRow2, 1) = "AAA $" Then
    wsUp.Cells(iRow2, 1).Value = "LLL"
    ElseIf Cells(iRow2, 1) = "LLL $" Then
    wsUp.Cells(iRow2, 1).Value = "LLL"
    ElseIf Cells(iRow2, 1) = "JJJ $" Then
    wsUp.Cells(iRow2, 1).Value = "JJ"

    End If

    wsUp.Activate
```

Code Breaks Here. I beleive because skips section above.

```
    vCN = 
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("Company").Range("B:B"), 
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(iRow2, 1), 
    Sheets("Company").Range("A:A"), 0), 1)
    wsUp.Range("B" & iRow2).Value = vCN
    vAN = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("COA").Range("B:B"), 
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(iRow2, 7), 
    Sheets("COA").Range("A:A"), 0), 1)
    wsUp.Range("H" & iRow2).Value = vAN
    sQLNE = wsUp.Cells(Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row
    wsUp.Range("N" & iRow2).Value = sQLNE
    wsUp.Range("S" & iRow2).Value = wsUp.Range("I" & iRow2).Value
    wsUp.Range("T" & iRow2).Value = wsUp.Range("J" & iRow2).Value
    Next iRow2



lastrow = wsUp.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
sBatch = wsInst.Cells(8, 2).Value
sMonth = wsInst.Cells(6, 2).Value
sYear = wsInst.Cells(7, 2).Value
sDate = wsInst.Cells(5, 2).Value
sRef = sBatch & sMonth & sYear
wsUp.Range("C2", "C" & lastrow).Value = sRef
wsUp.Range("f2", "F" & lastrow).Value = sRef
wsUp.Range("D2", "D" & lastrow).Value = "1"
wsUp.Range("e2", "E" & lastrow).Value = "0"
wsUp.Range("K2", "k" & lastrow).Value = sDate
wsUp.Range("I:J").NumberFormat = "0.00"
wsUp.Range("S:T").NumberFormat = "0.00"

For iRow2 = 2 To lastrow
If Cells(iRow2, 9) = "" Then
    wsUp.Cells(iRow2, 9).Value = "0.00"
    wsUp.Cells(iRow2, 19).Value = "0.00"
    ElseIf Cells(iRow2, 10) = "" Then
    wsUp.Cells(iRow2, 10).Value = "0.00"
    wsUp.Cells(iRow2, 20).Value = "0.00"
End If
Next iRow2

wsInst.Activate



End Sub
```

Comment: Complete this line by adding the parent sheet to it, if not it will use the active sheet as the reference and that is why it is skipping `If Cells(iRow2, 1) = "CCC $" Then`, it should be sth like `If MySheet.Cells(iRow2, 1) = "CCC $" Then` I don't know which one of the sheets is MySheet in your code, so replace it yourself

Comment: Thank you! That fixed it. I appreciate your help.

Comment: I put that as an answer so you can check it as the correct answer

Comment: What is weird is that the macro was working fine. The only thing I updated was the names inside the quotation marks as the headings changed. But it fixed it, so thats good.

Comment: always make sure you define your variables and objects at first and always address them when using in the code and do NOT let VBA use its default, for example, I see people are using cell, or range while it is open ended what the parent is

Comment: ^^^ was going to say the same.  Some care is given to use wsUp but to co-mingle with non explicit Cells is going to break.  Good coding practice is to always ensure the WB and WS are clearly known, or changes (or open WBs) will break your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code skips your `if` block because the parent for the cell has not been mentioned so it uses the `activesheet`, you have to explicitly mention that so instead of

`If Cells(iRow2, 1) = "CCC $" Then`

by this line:

`MySheet.Cells(iRow2, 1) = "CCC $" Then`

I don't know which one of the sheets is MySheet in your code, so replace it yourself